# how to Load YOLOv7 using torch.hub

Tags: pytorch, torch, yolov5, hub

how to load yolov7 model using torch.hub for make prediction

I directly use torch.hub.load method of yolov5 but it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

The answer is :

**First method**

```
!# Download YOLOv7 code
!git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7
%cd yolov7

from  hubconf import custom
model = custom(path_or_model='yolov7.pt')  # custom example
# model = create(name='yolov7', pretrained=True, channels=3, classes=80, autoshape=True)  # pretrained example

# Verify inference
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

imgs = [np.zeros((640, 480, 3))]

results = model(imgs)  # batched inference
results.print()
results.save()
```

**Second method**

**Load YOLOv7 using torch.hub**

```
!# Download YOLOv7 code
!git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7
%cd yolov7
from pathlib import Path

import torch

from models.yolo import Model
from utils.general import check_requirements, set_logging
from utils.google_utils import attempt_download
from utils.torch_utils import select_device

dependencies = ['torch', 'yaml']
check_requirements(Path("/content/yolov7/").parent / 'requirements.txt', exclude=('pycocotools', 'thop'))
set_logging()

def custom(path_or_model='path/to/model.pt', autoshape=True):
    """custom mode

    Arguments (3 options):
        path_or_model (str): 'path/to/model.pt'
        path_or_model (dict): torch.load('path/to/model.pt')
        path_or_model (nn.Module): torch.load('path/to/model.pt')['model']

    Returns:
        pytorch model
    """
    model = torch.load(path_or_model, map_location=torch.device('cpu')) if isinstance(path_or_model, str) else path_or_model  # load checkpoint
    if isinstance(model, dict):
        model = model['ema' if model.get('ema') else 'model']  # load model

    hub_model = Model(model.yaml).to(next(model.parameters()).device)  # create
    hub_model.load_state_dict(model.float().state_dict())  # load state_dict
    hub_model.names = model.names  # class names
    if autoshape:
        hub_model = hub_model.autoshape()  # for file/URI/PIL/cv2/np inputs and NMS
    device = select_device('0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')  # default to GPU if available
    return hub_model.to(device)

model = custom(path_or_model='yolov7.pt')  # custom example
# model = create(name='yolov7', pretrained=True, channels=3, classes=80, autoshape=True)  # pretrained example

# Verify inference
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

imgs = [np.zeros((640, 480, 3))]

results = model(imgs)  # batched inference
results.print()
results.save()
df_prediction = results.pandas().xyxy
df_prediction
```

full code on [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nKoC-_areXmc_20Xn7z6kcqHEKU7SJsX#scrollTo=yyB_MQW1OWhZ)

Answer (score 4):

The Yolov7 model was fine-tuned on custom dataset with this repo: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

```
import torch
import os
import cv2

# Load fine-tuned custom model
model = torch.hub.load('WongKinYiu/yolov7', 'custom', '/path/to/custom_model.pt',
                        force_reload=True, trust_repo=True)

    
# Declaring some variables    
TABLE_CONFIDENCE = 0.50
CELL_CONFIDENCE = 0.50
OUTPUT_DIR = 'output'

# Bounding Boxes color scheme
ALPHA = 0.2
TABLE_BORDER = (0, 0, 255)
CELL_FILL = (0, 0, 200)
CELL_BORDER = (0, 0, 255)

os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
    
# Run the Inference and draw predicted bboxes
results = model(image_path)
df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
table_bboxes = []
cell_bboxes = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['class'] == 0 and row['confidence'] > TABLE_CONFIDENCE:
        table_bboxes.append([int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']),
                             int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])])

    if row['class'] == 1 and row['confidence'] > CELL_CONFIDENCE:
        cell_bboxes.append([int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']),
                            int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])])

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
overlay = image.copy()
for table_bbox in table_bboxes:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (table_bbox[0], table_bbox[1]),
                  (table_bbox[2], table_bbox[3]), TABLE_BORDER, 1)

for cell_bbox in cell_bboxes:
    cv2.rectangle(overlay, (cell_bbox[0], cell_bbox[1]),
                  (cell_bbox[2], cell_bbox[3]), CELL_FILL, -1)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (cell_bbox[0], cell_bbox[1]),
                  (cell_bbox[2], cell_bbox[3]), CELL_BORDER, 1)

image_new = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, ALPHA, image, 1-ALPHA, 0)
image_filename = image_path.split('/')[-1]
cv2.imwrite(f'{OUTPUT_DIR}/{image_filename}', image_new)
```